# Is this an SMC connector?

Tags: rf, connector, identification

Can anyone identify this tiny connector?  The tape measure is in inches.  The connector has threads on the outside and a pin inside.  The diameter is about 1/16th of an inch.  I think it might be an SMC connector but I am not an expert in this stuff.

This connector is on an accelerometer.  I will need to get a custom cable to connect to the accelerometer; the other end will be a BNC connector.  Does anyone know what type of cable I would want to use for this?  My lab mainly uses BNC cables, and they're all RG58, which is way too big for this tiny accelerometer.

[image: Side view of connector]

[image: Front view of connector]

Comment: Is this the same connector you asked about in another question? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81136/is-this-an-sma-female-connector

Comment: No, this is a different and smaller connector.  This one is on an accelerometer.

Comment: No, while the pin/socket polarity is correct for SMC, SMC uses a #10-32 thread which is substantially larger than "1/16th of an inch" in diameter.  Also, online pictures of SMC connectors show more of "nose" protruding beyond the threaded portion.

Comment: The documentation mentions the accelerometer comes with a "Coax Cable, 10 ft (3 m), 3-56 plug to 10-32 plug" but I couldn't find any info on what a 3-56 plug is.

Comment: Those are both machine screw sizes, perhaps someone made custom connectors out of them.  If your sensor bandwidth is not multiple MHz you might be able to improvise with brass hardware.  But 3-56 is a bit uncommon compared to 2-56 and 4-40.  Searching for older connectors with that thread might be effective.

Comment: Picture of the mating connector here: http://www.pcb.com/spec_sheet.asp?model=EK

Comment: @markrages - looks like the start of an answer?

Comment: @ChrisStratton that's all I got.  It appears to be a special, oddball connector.  I couldn't find anything from the usual connector manufacturers.  So I'm giving up.

Comment: There are additional mentions of the 3-56 connector at http://www.synotech.de/ which also has references to the pcb.com site - probably contacting one or both of those companies would lead to a way to buy a cable.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add this as a new answer.
 Mark & Chris are correct - it is NOT a SSMA connector.
This answer is based on an extension of what they discovered 
The cable designed for use with the accelerometer is shown here

PCB Piezotronics -
[Model: 030A10 Miniature, low-noise, blue coaxial cable, 10-ft, 3-56 plug to 10-32 plug](http://www.pcb.com/Products.aspx?m=030A10#.UiruodISaOY)

[image]

If you want the "EK" connector only it is here (as Chris advised): [EK connector -](http://www.pcb.com/spec_sheet.asp?model=EK)

Coupling Thread 3-56 female
    Size - OD   0.12 in  / 3.0 mm
    Size - Length   0.29 in  / 7.4 mm

[image]

With the above information an excessively enthused technician could construct a workable plug

**OR** ...

[PCB Piezotronics contact page:](http://www.pcb.com/Contact.aspx#.UirxHdISaOY)

Answer (score 0):

That **appears to be** an "RP SSMA" or "Reverse Polarity SSMA" connector

IF you find an SSMA (or other connector of the same size but it is not an RP version as your is, you could make an adequately workable one off by machining down a plug (whose centre will fit your plug) and then ensuring that adequate outer contact is made. Even if this involved bonding (eg soldering) your unit to a cut down plug it would work if done well.

SSMA is a (even more) miniature version of SMA.
RP or reverse polarity is when the plug centre is a male pin rather than a socket and the outer is a male thread, as shown in your picture.

This image from [Wikipedia - SMA Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector) shows an RP connector (as yours is) but this is an SMA.

[image]

[Amphenol SSMA with catalog - may not have RP](http://www.amphenolconnex.com/product-specifications/ssma)

[Southwest Microwave](http://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/products/connectors.php?family=SSMA) - have SSMA PLUS smaller, still smaller and still still smaller versions.
One MAY match yours. May not have RP.
2.92 mm, 2.40 mm, 1.85 mm versions !!!
[1.85mm - 67 GHz !!! - not RP as shown here](http://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/products/family.php?family=236)

[Dimension chart below from here](http://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/products/family.php?family=238)

[image]

**RELATED:**

[PCI](http://www.precisionconnector.com/html/connectorSeriesList_SSMA.html)

[Notionally reverse SSMA images - MAY be of some use](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ssma+connector&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ZBEpUrIwxJeJB4q2gcAP&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=2133&bih=1201#q=reverse%20ssma%20connector&tbm=isch) - note that many are not RP SSMA.

[Future RP SMA - MAY know of SSMA](http://www.futureelectronics.com/en/technologies/interconnect/connectors-rf/sma-ssma-connectors/Pages/8920951-CONREVSMA001.aspx?IM=0)

[Aliexpress and similar can be a source of specialist parts](http://www.aliexpress.com/price/sma-connector-pcb-price.html) - these are not exactly what you want but show that small volume sellers of semi-specialist parts can be found.
[Also hgere](http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=ssma+connector+&catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20130905152339)

[RF Globalnet SSMA](http://www.rfglobalnet.com/doc/ssma-rf-coaxial-connectors-0001)

[Microwave 101 connector page](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedia/connectors.cfm)

[SMS](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedia/connectors_smc.cfm)
[Smaller ...](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedia/connectorsprecision.cfm#1mm)

[Amphenol may save you - or not](http://www.amphenolconnex.com/product-specifications/ssma)

[Southwest microwave catalog pages](http://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/static/appendix.pdf)

[... beyond the catalog.](http://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/static/beyond.pdf)

Comment: With the 3-56 thread specified, it's less than half the size of an SSMA.  It may be worth remembering that it is an accelerometer with a bandwidth that likely extends barely into the MHz range (and probably quite a bit less), rather than a microwave system - it's probably a coaxial connector for the same reasons audio cables are, threaded for security, and tiny to keep it very low mass.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not an RF/microwave connector, but a special "3-56 coaxial" or "EK" accelerometer/instrumentation connector.

markrages found mention of it at:

http://www.pcb.com/spec_sheet.asp?model=EK

I also find it mentioned at:

http://www.synotech.de/uploads/tx_ttproducts/datasheet/PCB_102_352A71.pdf

Which has pictures and specs of units of the same sort you have, though on further reading it appears they are just a distributor and point back to PCB as the manufacturer.

Contacting one or both companies would probably be the best way to track down a source for a cable or connector, which may be part 030A10.