# Is this an SMA female connector?

Tags: rf, connector, identification, cable-assemblies

Can anyone identify this coax connector?  I think it might be an SMA female connector but I'm no expert.  It has threads on the outside and a hole inside.  The diameter (to the outside of the threads) is 5.25 mm.  The pink ruler in the first picture is in cm.  The yellow tape measure in the second picture is in inches.

The connector is on a shaker that I need to connect to an amplifier.  The cable that connects them is missing, so I'm going to get a custom one.  The other end of the cable will have a dual banana plug.  Is there a particular type of cable I should use in this application?

UPDATE: it's not SMA.  Or SMB, for that matter; I took it to a hardware store yesterday and tried both.  They didn't have any SSMA or SMC for me to try, though, so I suppose it could be one of those...

[image: Coax connector in mm]
[image]

Comment: Might want to take a better photo that shows the thread and internal pin more clearly. Higher resolution wouldn't hurt, either. It's kinda hard to see from the photo you posted.

Comment: I've added a better picture, I hope that helps.  And there is no pin inside, by the way.

Comment: It won't be an SMA unless your measurement is quite a bit off, to the outside threads of an SMA female should be 6.24mm and as a double-check I just measured one as 6.29mm using calipers.

Comment: Update: you're right, it's not SMA.  Or SMB, for that matter; I took it to a hardware store yesterday and tried both.  They didn't have any SSMA or SMC for me to try, though, so I suppose it could be one of those...

Answer (score 2):

### Maybe...

The SMA female would generally fit the description and is commonly used in these types of applications.

### However...

The threading (I don't really see it in the photos), if present, looks either way too fine or way too coarse. The barrel also looks too short to be SMA, but again that's just the photo?

### To test...

Get a 0.312" (5/16") outer-diameter (lands spacing) hex nut *with 1/4" 36TPI* threading from your local hardware store.

[image]
This is the Tyco Electronics 2-332004-0: 5/16" 1/4-36 Steel Hex Nut

If you don't have good hardware stores (like we have in Silicon Valley), you can order [one](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=-986&y=-74&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=A104989-ND) from Digikey or other online vendors.

If it threads on (don't force it!) then you are almost certainly dealing with an SMA given your other connector properties.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Incorrect.   The threads on an SMA are 1/4-36 which is not a hardware store size. The wrench nut is 5/16" across the flats but not the threads, so a 5/16 nut will not fit, and neither will a 1/4-20 nor a 1/4-28.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about what I wrote. I did however omit the threading. That has been corrected. Thank you for the report.

Comment: I've also added a reference to a nut to show that you can buy them as described.

Comment: @DrFriedParts For a moment I interpreted "*you can order one from Digikey*" as ordering a good hardware store. :-)

Comment: Considering that the entire nut test, as posted, would lead to false conclusion, yes, **you did indeed post incorrect information**.

Comment: @Chris -- Huh? You seem to being saying (1) That a 5/16" nut will not fit -- false; 5/16" 1/4-36 is precisely the spec'd size for the nut and a specific part number was provided as an example and (2) hardware stores don't carry it -- which is subjective, we have them here.

Comment: Indeed, I am saying that a 5/16 nut will not fit, because that is a fact.  **Nuts are specified by their thread major diameter and pitch, not their size across flats**.  The only information you had posted - 5/16" - was either entirely **irrelevant** to the test you proposed (we aren't checking which wrench will fit), or, in the reading of anyone familiar with the language of mechanical hardware, a suggestion to test against a different and entirely incompatible nut with a 5/16" thread major diameter.  The test should be performed with a 1/4-36 nut, **which is NOT** a 5/16 nut.

Comment: Yay! More bolded text! @Chris, look I like you, but your position here is ridiculous. (1) Nuts, fully specified, must include outer diameter, material, etc... (typ. that's handled by using a "standards table", but there are many of these). (2) If you look at the post you are staring at a nut (and mfr description) that says otherwise. (3) Do you really expect us to accept that there is one **and only one** nut in the entire planet's inventory that is 1/4-36? ...and that its outer diameter is **never** 5/16?

Comment: You need a 1/4-36 nut.  The OD is irrelevant to the application.  When only one dimension is given as you had, that is the thread major diameter size - the item your post now pictures is not a "5/16" nut, and your mistake was in calling it such. Calling out only the size across flats instead of the thread major diameter gives no helpful information for the fit and only misleads those who assume you would be conforming to standards.  A "5/16 nut" will not fit, a 1/4-36 will.

Comment: @Chris -- (1) Not calling out the major and pitch was most certainly a problematic omission on my part and I corrected this as soon as you brought it to my attention (thank you). (2) You are making a straw man argument. Nowhere is it called a "5/16 nut", it's called a "5/16 1/4-36 nut". (3) The OD is quite relevant since SMA-M have a 5/16" OD and this will line up with the flange of his mounted connector if it's SMA-F adding more circumstantial evidence to the investigation.